# How to not affect current route and change 'Title' of NavigationBarRouteMapper directly -- React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Following is snippet:

```
var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
    ...
   ,
    RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState){
      return(
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{
            //Once clicked, I would like it to rerender the NavigationBarRouteMapper's Title directly without having to change the current route
          }
        }>
          <Text>Button</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      )
    },
    Title(route, navigator, index, navState){
        //e.g. if(route.name == 'ButtonPressed'){return <Text>New Title</Text>} else return null
```

Once the RightButton is clicked, I would want it to render the Title to

```
<Text>New Title</Text>
```

if not just return null. Is there a way to do so without having to change the current route?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is supported at the moment. The `NavigatorIOS` module was dumped by Facebook and now maintained by the community, so I doubt that it will be resolved any time soon.. you can track [the issue here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/476).

Instead, you can use [`NavigationExperimental`](https://github.com/ericvicenti/navigation-rfc) to achieve the same result (although it might get hairier as this is only half-backed). Check out `NavigationExperimental` in [UIExplorer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer) to see for yourself.

Comment: got it. I'll take a look. thank you Kuf! One last question I have if you don't mind ;) You've really been helpful! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489478/how-can-i-pass-refs-into-variable-of-navigationbar-routemapper-react-native