# How can I update state once onPress via TouchableOpacity in React Native?

Tags: react-native, reactjs

So I am rendering a ListView with two columns of items. The following function renders the rows, renderRow(rowData):

For each item, if clicked, I want it to be changed to opacity of 0.5 and if clicked again, want it to be back to clear up the opacity, so what I was thinking is setting it to opacity of 1.0.

I tried the following, but for some reason the opacity is not being updated:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      opacity: 1.0,
      selected: false,
    }
  }

  renderRow(rowData){
    return (
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>this._selected() underlayColor='transparent'}>
              <View style={{opacity:this.state.opacity}}>
                <Text>{rowData.firstName}</Text>
                <Text>{rowData.lastName}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
    )
  }

  _selected(){
    if(this.state.selected){
      console.log('ITEM HAS BEEN UNSELECTED')
      this.setState({
        opacity: 1.0,
        selected: false
      })
    }else{
      console.log('ITEM HAS BEEN SELECTED')
      this.setState({
        opacity: 0.5,
        selected: true
      })
    }
  }
```

Why isn't the opacity being updated once clicked and rerendering the view inside the TouchableHighlight? Also how can I do so with individual item, with each's 'opacity' and 'selected' states?

**FULL CODE

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

class Interest extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

    this.state = {
      selected: false,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
      {firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Boy'},
      {firstName: 'Shawn', lastName: 'Ke'},
      {firstName: 'An', lastName: 'Twon'}
    };
  }

  renderRow(rowData){
    return (
          <View style={this.state.selected ? styles.transItem : styles.opacItem}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={ () => { this.setState({selected: !this.state.selected})}} underlayColor='transparent'>
              <View>
                <Text>{rowData.firstName}</Text>
                <Text>{rowData.lastName}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list} dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  list: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  opacItem: {
    margin: 15,
    width: 155,
    height: 175,
    opacity: 1.0
  },
  transItem: {
    margin: 15,
    width: 155,
    height: 175,
    opacity: 0.5
  }
});

export default Interest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you set the selected state that is not intended.

In the code above, the selected is a state for the entire app - not just for a selected line. To select a single line, you should keep a selected state for each item. For cleaner code it is recommended to have another module for the item, and keep the state there and not in the parent module.

Code:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

class Interest extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
        {firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Boy'},
        {firstName: 'Shawn', lastName: 'Ke'},
        {firstName: 'An', lastName: 'Twon'}
      ])};
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ListView
            contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this._renderRow}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }

    _renderRow(rowData) {
      return(
        <InterestItem rowData={rowData} />);
    }
  }

  class InterestItem extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        selected: false
      }
    }

    render(){
      const { rowData } = this.props;
      return (
        <View style={this.state.selected ? styles.transItem : styles.opacItem}>
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={ () => { this.setState({selected: !this.state.selected})}}
            underlayColor='transparent'
          >
            <View>
              <Text>{rowData.firstName}</Text>
              <Text>{rowData.lastName}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1
    },
    list: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    opacItem: {
      margin: 15,
      width: 155,
      height: 175,
      opacity: 1.0
    },
    transItem: {
      margin: 15,
      width: 155,
      height: 175,
      opacity: 0.5
    }
  });

  export default Interest
```

Comment: I made the attempt but unfortunately it's still not updating the state once clicked. I've updated the original post with the new implementation under **NEW EDIT. It all makes sense but still don't know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Just checking to see if you've seen my previous message. Please let me know.

Comment: Tried the this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this) but unfortunately it still does not work, so I posted the full code in the original post under **FULL CODE. Been stuck on this forever..

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you so much! You the savior! I have one small question. Do you know why when I click the the InterestItem, it lags for a bit and then applies the opacity? Does that occur to you as well?

Comment: @JoKo no, for me it changes immediately, so I guess it has something to do with how you run it. try running it on a device or without any debug flags, that should make it faster. If it worked please [access my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Gotcha! Just accepted your answer! If you don't mind. Could you take a look at this as well? Thanks Kuf! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444018/how-to-not-affect-current-route-and-change-title-of-navigationbarroutemapper-d