# How can I pass refs into variable of NavigationBar routeMapper (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

Following is the UPDATED code -- I am trying to implement react-native-drawer from https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer and the variable I passed into NavigationBarRouteMapper logs openDrawer() function properly, yet when the left nav button is clicked it does nothing:

```
class practice extends Component {
...

  openDrawer(){
    this._drawer.open()
  }

  render() {
    return (
  <Drawer
    content={<DrawerPanel/>}
    openDrawerOffset={100}
    ref={(ref) => this._drawer = ref}
    type='static'
    tweenHandler={Drawer.tweenPresets.parallax}
  >
        <Navigator
          configureScene={this.configureScene}
          initialRoute={{name: 'Start', component: Start}}
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          style={styles.container}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar
              style={styles.navBar}
              routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper(this.openDrawer)}
            />
          }
        />
  </Drawer>
    );
  }
}

var NavigationBarRouteMapper = openDrawer => ({
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState){
      return(
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=>{openDrawer}}>
              <Text>Open Menu</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
      )
    }
  },...
```

What may be stopping the drawer from opening? Seems like everything has been implemented properly.

Comment: @NaderDabit Still stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the scope of the `testingString` variable.  When you `console.log(this.testingString)`, `this` points to the object returned by the `NavigationBarRouteMapper` function.  You haven't set a `testingString` variable on this object, so it will return undefined.

To get the variable you passed into the function in this way, simply use `testingString`, and not `this.testingString`.

**Edit regarding the openDrawer function**

You're passing a function that *returns* your `openDrawer` function instead of calling it.  You'll want to pass `onPress={openDrawer}` or `onPress={() => openDrawer()}` as your prop.

Comment: Thank you! It was able to log properly. Now to take this step further to learn, I updated the original post with additional code, yet it still does not function as intended. What may be the issue?

Comment: Thank you so much! Just accepted the answer. If you don't mind could you take another issue that I came across? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519655/how-to-pass-navigator-reference-to-react-native-drawer